# Arch Linux: fontspec does not find system fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I am running an Arch Linux / Windows 7 dual boot laptop.

The windows partition is mounted under arch and i made the windows fonts usable with `ln -s /windows/Windows/fonts/ /usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts`

This works, every program besides luaLaTeX with fontspec has acces to the fonts, e.g. libreoffice.

But i am not able to use the fonts with:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmaintfont{Comic Sans MS}
```

The result is the font-not-found message from fontspec.
Under the Windows 7 partition it works just fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:
Lua uses a font name data base, which I had to update using the command:

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

Comment: What version of Luaotfload do you run?
You can find out running ``luaotfload-tool --version``.
The current version (2.5) should update the font index 
automatically if a font couldn’t be found, unless you
explicitly disabled the updates in the configuration file.
In any case it should work on Arch because that’s the
platform it is being developed on.
If not then you most likely found a bug.

Comment: I keep my packages up to date, so it's the version currently delivered by the texlive packages. Version is 2.4.-3

Comment: That’s an old one and it had the bug you describe.
Unfortunately, the TeX packages in most distros are
crap and Arch is no exception. You could install a
current TeX live yourself, otherwise you will have
to wait for the Arch maintainers to catch up.

Comment: Probably the Best solution

Comment: @MaxNoe Which? Installing vanilla TL from upstream is especially easy on Arch because it is especially easy to create the 'dummy' package `pacman` needs if you want to install things which have `texlive` packages as dependencies. (I believe there is an AUR package although it is not really easier than just doing it yourself.)

Comment: i installed texlive 2014 from tug and the AUR `texlive-dummy` package now and everything seems to work fine